# Functions and function pointers in C++

Tags: c++, function, templates, c++11, function-pointers

With reference to the following code

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
#include <vector>
using std::vector;

void function() {
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
}

int main() {
    vector<void (*) ()> functions;
    functions.push_back(function);         // (1) no error
    functions.push_back(&function);        // (2) no error
    for (const auto& func : functions) {
        func();
    }

    // vector<decltype(function)> vec;     // (3) error
    return 0;
}
```

There seems to be an error when I uncomment (3), I am just trying to understand the reasoning behind this.  When I pass in a function as the argument to a templated function does it resolve the type to a function pointer? It would make sense for the compiler to deduce all function types as such to a function pointer but why then does the decltype() not resolve to a function pointer?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I recommend the use of `std::function` instead of function pointers. It's more readable, and you don't deal with whether it is a pointer or not.

Comment: @AdiLevin `std::function` should only be used when necessary, that is when one really wants to store (!) callables that have nothing in common but being callable (with the respective arguments, returning the respective type). It adds a lot of overhead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`decltype(function)` is `void()` - a function.
what you need is the decayed version of a function - `void(*)()`:

```
std::decay<decltype(function)>::type

std::vector < std::decay<decltype(function)>::type > myPtrFunctionVec;
```

PS.
if you're working with VC++ (visual stdio) you can easily see the type deduced from `decltype` by printing `typeid(decltype(XXX)).name()`. VC++, unlike other compilers, gives the undecorated name of a type. very handy for metaprogramming debugging.

***EDIT:***
as @Daniel Jour has commented, the solution `decltype(&function)` workd as well, because the construct `&f` gives the pointer to `f`, which is what you need

Comment: `std::decay` is a good idea, wasn't thinking of it. You could also just `decltype(&function)`: http://ideone.com/Af98uJ

Comment: @DanielJour cool! I wasn't aware that that expression will yield a pointer to function!

Comment: @DavidHaim Nor was I.  It's one of those things that you wouldn't think would work, until you look at it again and realise it makes perfect sense.  `&function` is a function pointer, so logically passing it to `decltype` would evaluate to the function pointer's type.  It's just too simple to be obvious, though.

Comment: @DanielJour your solution is shorter and more correct than mine, post it

Comment: @DavidHaim Just add it to your answer, it's basically just doing the decay (from function to function pointer) manually.

Comment: One more question.  So if decltype(function) does resolve to void(), why would it cause such drastic errors?  I'm guessing its because functions aren't first class here but just wanted to make sure.

Comment: the functions sit somwhere else in the memory as assembly instructions, you can't store that in a vector. what you can store is a pointer to something that will initialize a call to the assembly instructions. you can't store functions, only pointer to functions

Comment: well, technically, if you write  a JIT compiler, you can, but that is completly different talk